# eventListener not removed on clicking

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove an eventListener when clicking on an Canvas element:

```js
document.getElementById("canvas")
        .addEventListener("click", setPath, false);

function setPath() {
  if (check) {
    document.getElementById("canvas").
        addEventListener("mousemove", mouseOverPath, false);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("canvas").
        removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseOverPath, false);
  }

  function mouseOverPath(event) {
    drawLine.x = event.clientX;
    drawLine.y = event.clientY;
    drawLine.draw();
  }

}

document.getElementById("canvas").
        addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (check == true) {
    check = false;
  } else if (check == false) {
    check = true;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200" style="border:1px solid black;">
```

The if-statements are executed correctly but the removeEventListener isn't.

The check part:

Comment: Are you sure the if-statements are executed correctly? Where is the variable check on the setPath function?

Comment: I am. The check variable is in the scope above. Also tested with console.log

Comment: I am betting you call `setPath` multiple times so you bind multiple events. Not seeing how `check` is set makes it hard to help.

Comment: @epascarello The setPath function is just executed in the click event you see above.

Comment: Yes, but if you click 2 times and check is true, than you bind two click events.

Comment: I addet the part.

Comment: Hum.. Does it not solve or problem if you use mousedown instead of click? Click event will wait for mouseup, so only when the mouse is up it will be fired. If you're ttrying to simulate mouse drag, this is not it.

Comment: Weird it is not in the click event. How is `check` set originally?

Comment: I set check at "false" to begin with. And the if statement is called alternately, so that's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is that you define `mouseOverPath` within `setPath`:

```js
function setPath() {
  if (check) {
    document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", mouseOverPath, false);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("canvas").removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseOverPath, false);
  }

  function mouseOverPath(event) {
    drawLine.x = event.clientX;
    drawLine.y = event.clientY;
    drawLine.draw();
  }

}
```

For every call of `setPath` the `mouseOverPath` is a different object, so the  `mouseOverPath`  for the `addEventListener` and the one for `removeEventListener` refer to different objects, and as of that `removeEventListener` does nothing.

You need to move the `mouseOverPath` function out if the `setPath`  function.

Here a simplified test case of your problem:

```js
var tmp;

function test() {
  if (!tmp) {
     // save the current foo for the first call of test
    tmp = foo
  } else {
    // the comparison of the current foo with tmp (the previous foo) is false
    console.log(tmp == foo)
  }

  function foo() {}
}

test()
test()
```

Comment: Well, thank you. That worked perfectly! And also a pretty good explanation. :)